# Let  = ∑  be a sum of  random variables. Additivity of random expectation Show that () = ∑  ().

Tags: summation, random-variables

Let  = ∑  be a sum of  random variables.
Show that () = ∑ ().

I try to show that but i can't. if it possible for you help me in this case.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.